# How do I create an open file dialog in a xcode cocoa project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, openfiledialog

I'm looking for an equivalent to GetOpenFileName function for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard Cocoa class for Open File UI is [NSOpenPanel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Example code:

```
//this gives you a copy of an open file dialogue
NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

//set the title of the dialogue window
openPanel.title = @"Choose a .PED texture file";

//shoud the user be able to resize the window?
openPanel.showsResizeIndicator = YES;

//should the user see hidden files (for user apps - usually no)
openPanel.showsHiddenFiles = NO;

//can the user select a directory?
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = NO;

//can the user create directories while using the dialogue?
openPanel.canCreateDirectories = YES;

//should the user be able to select multiple files?
openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;

//an array of file extensions to filter the file list
openPanel.allowedFileTypes = @[@"ped"];

//this launches the dialogue
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:appDelegate.controlsWindow
                completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {

                    //if the result is NSOKButton
                    //the user selected a file
                    if (result==NSOKButton) {

                        //get the selected file URLs
                        NSURL *selection = openPanel.URLs[0];

                        //finally store the selected file path as a string
                        NSString* path = [[selection path] stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath];

                        //here add yuor own code to open the file

                    }

                }];
```

Comment: how to add "show options" button in the dialog?